# how to access the next in a linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, private

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class car{
    private:
    string color;
    int mileage;
    int topSpeed;
    int numGears;
    public:
};

class carNode{
    private:
    car Car;
    carNode *next;
    friend class carLinkedlist;
};

class carLinkedlist{
    public:
    carLinkedlist();
    ~carLinkedlist();
    bool empty() const;
    void addtolist(const car& theCar);
    const carNode* getHead();
    private:
    carNode* head;
};

const carNode* carLinkedlist::getHead(){
    return head;
} 

void car::setDetails(const string color,const int mileage,const int topSpeed,const int numGears){
    this->color = color;
    this->mileage = mileage;
    this->topSpeed = topSpeed;
    this->numGears = numGears;
}

carLinkedlist::carLinkedlist(){
    head = NULL;
}

carLinkedlist::~carLinkedlist(){
    // what to do here
}

bool carLinkedlist::empty() const{
    if (head==NULL)
        return true;
    return false;
}

void carLinkedlist::addtolist(const car& theCar){
    if (empty()){
        head = new carNode;
        head->Car = theCar;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else{
        carNode* temp = new carNode;
        temp->Car = theCar;
        temp->next = NULL;
        head->next = temp;
    }
}

int main(){
    car car1;
    car1.setDetails("red",40,140,5);
    const car& carr1 = car1;
    car car2;
    car2.setDetails("black",30,220,5);
    const car& carr2 = car2;
    carLinkedlist carList;
    carList.addtolist(carr1);
    carList.addtolist(carr2);
    //cout << car1.getColor() << endl;
    cout << (carList.getHead())->next->Car.getColor() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code throws error in the second last line as next and Car are both private. I can make a getCar function to access the value of Car but what to do for the protected next, how can I access its value.

P.S. I made the getHead function for a similar reason i.e. to access the head but I can't access the next by making function 'cause then there will be next->next protected.
Also please verify if I should make a getCar function or do something else.

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::list` if you want a linked list data structure? (hint: `std::vector` will usually out-perform it).

Comment: @jesper cause i have to implement my own linked list

Comment: To get this kind of code working reliably it's best to write some unit tests to verify functionality incrementally before charging head-long into using it.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use the `this->` syntax to access class members unless the member has the same name as a parameter or local variable.

Comment: You are going to have trouble using classes with no public interface.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make the `next` member `public`.

Another solution is to add a `link_to` function inside `carNode`:

```
class carNode
{
  public:  
    void link_to(carNode& cn)
    {
        next = &cn;
    }
  private:
  //...
};
```